# Spacing issue with custom thesis package

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I'm having issues with vertical spacing in my thesis. I'm not sure if this style related or something that is "standard" with the report class. I've written lots of stuff mostly in the article class and don't recall ever dealing with this problem. Here's is the style code.

```
% make it a modern package - BPG
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{USCthesis}[2003/07/16 v3.2]

%%
%% Declare the dissertation style
%%
\typeout{Dissertation/thesis package USCthesis Version 3.2 as
          of 16 July 2003}

%%
%% the following option-parsing code is changed to conform to the LaTeX2e
%% package interface - BPG

%%
%%  Define style option flags
%%
\newif\ifthesis
\DeclareOption{dissertation}{
  \thesisfalse   % Default
}
\DeclareOption{thesis} {
  \thesistrue
}

\newif\ifproposal
\DeclareOption{final} {
  \proposalfalse        % Default
}
\DeclareOption{proposal} {
  \proposaltrue
}


\newif\ifcopyright
\DeclareOption{copyright} {
  \copyrighttrue
}
\DeclareOption{nocopyright} {
  \copyrightfalse
}

\DeclareOption{fussy} {
  \fussy                         % Default
}
\DeclareOption{sloppy} {
  \sloppy
}

\newif\ifflushbottom
\DeclareOption{flushbottom} {
  \flushbottomtrue                         % Default
}
\DeclareOption{raggedbottom} {
  \flushbottomfalse
}

\newif\ifopenbib
\DeclareOption{opref} {
  \openbibtrue
}
\DeclareOption{clref} {
  \def\ds@clref{\openbibfalse}         % Default
}


\newif\if@techreport
\DeclareOption{techreport} {
  \@techreporttrue                   %   the option is present, but
  \xdef\@optionfiles{%                   still add to the \@optionfiles
    \@optionfiles                    %   list.
    \@elt techreport.sty\relax
}}


% set the defaults
\ExecuteOptions{dissertation,final,copyright,fussy,clref,flushbottom}
\ProcessOptions

%%
%% Define the Layout adjustment commands.  Initialization of values is
%% made after loading the report style.
%%
\def\pagetop#1{%
  \global \topmargin #1             % Nominal distance from page top to
  \global\advance \topmargin -1.0 true in} %   top of boxwith running head.

\def\pageleft{%
  \@ifnextchar [%
    {\@pageleft}%
    {\@pageleft[0pt]}}

\def\@pageleft[#1]#2{%
  \if@twoside
    %% Values for two-sided printing: (1/2 inch gutter margin)
    \global \oddsidemargin #2          % Left margin on odd-numbered pages.
    \global\advance \oddsidemargin -1.0 true in
    \global \evensidemargin #2         % Left margin on even-numbered pages.
    \global\advance \evensidemargin -1.5 true in
    \global\advance \evensidemargin #1 % Adjustment for fine-tuning gutter
                                       %   margin
    \flushbottom
    \ifproposal\else\if@techreport\else
       \typeout{Warning: Thesis/Dissertation should be
                           printed on one side only.}
    \fi\fi
  \else
    %% Values for one-sided printing:
    \global \oddsidemargin #2
    \global\advance \oddsidemargin -1.0 true in
    \global \evensidemargin \oddsidemargin
    \raggedbottom
  \fi}

%
% \footheight disappears in LaTeX2e (it was never used in 2.09 anyway).  as
% such, \pageheight now takes just one arg and doesn't manipulate \footheight
%    - BPG
%\def\@pageheight[#1]#2{%
  %\global \footheight #1%
  %\global \textheight #2%
  %\global\advance \textheight -\footheight}
\def\pageheight#1{\global \textheight #1}

\def\pagewidth#1{\global \textwidth #1}

\def\pagemargin#1{\global \footskip #1\baselineskip}

%%
%% Let the user declare the document to be of \documentclass{report},
%% then \usepackage{USCthesis} -BPG
%%
%%\usepackage{doublespace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%%
%% Modify Penalties
%%
\brokenpenalty 10000       % Disallow page breaks at hyphens (this
               % will give some underfull vbox's, so an
               % alternative is to use \brokenpenalty=100
               % and manually search for and fix such page
               % breaks)
\clubpenalty 10000         % Disallow club (orphan) lines
\displaywidowpenalty 10000 % Disallow widow lines before display
\widowpenalty 10000        % Disallow widow lines

%%
%% Disallow x- or -xx breaks.  But if used in an old TeX, we will just
%% have to do without and hope for the best.
%%
\ifx\undefined\inputlineno\else
  \lefthyphenmin=2
  \righthyphenmin=3
\fi

%%
%% Set the Page Style Parameters
%%
\@addtoreset{equation}{chapter}   % Have the equation reset in each chapter
\headheight 0.0 true pt           % Height of box containing running head
\headsep    0.0 true pt           % Size of strut between head and text
\topskip   10.0 true pt           % Baselineskip for the first line of page
\itemsep    0.0 true pt           % Extra vertical space, in addition to
                                  %   \parskip, added between list items

\pagetop{1.1 true in}    % 1 inch plus allowance
\pageleft{1.6 true in}   % 1.5 inches plus allowance
\pageheight{8.5 true in} % 9 inches minus allowance
\pagewidth{5.85 true in}  % 6 inches minus allowance
\pagemargin{2.0}          % Number of (unstretched) lines
                          % between text and page number

\setstretch{2.0}          % get "real" double spacing?

\ifflushbottom
  \flushbottom
\fi

%%
%% Redefine some font sizes so that things don't get too big.
%%
\let\LARGE=\Large
\let\huge=\Large
\let\Huge=\Large

%%
%% Redefine plain style page to move the page number to the lower
%% right corner.
%%
\if@twoside
  \def\ps@plain{%
    \def\@oddhead{}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\rm\thepage}%
    \def\@evenhead{}
    \def\@evenfoot{\rm\thepage\hfil}}%
\else
  \def\ps@plain{%
    \def\@oddhead{}%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\rm\thepage}%
    \def\@evenhead{}
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}%
\fi

%%
%% Define Title Page Macros
%%
%% \title and \author is defined in latex.tex, but we will need to
%% redefine \title to allow the optional argument.  Also, the \thanks
%% command is disabled and such footnotes will be thrown away or will
%% appear in the wrong place.
%%
\def\title{%
  \@ifnextchar [%
    {\@title}%
    {\@title[\@empty]}}

\def\@title[#1]#2{%
  \gdef\@volume{#1}%
  \gdef\@title{#2}}

%%
%% The \addvolumecontents will add the contents of other volumes to
%% the current volume. This command should be placed after the
%% \begin{document} for earlier volumes and before the \end{document}
%% for later ones.
%%
\def\thesisinput#1{%
  \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \let\thesisinput=\@gobble % Inhibit recursive \thesisinput's
      \@input{#1}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\def\addvolumecontents{%
  \@ifnextchar [%
    {\@addvolumecontents}%
    {\@addvolumecontents[toc]}}

\long\def\@addvolumecontents[#1]#2{%
  \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \let\label\@gobble
      \let\index\@gobble
      \let\glossary\@gobble
      \def\protect##1{\string\string\string##1\string\space \space}%
      \edef\@tempa{%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{%
          \string\@writefile{#1}{\protect \thesisinput{#2.#1}}}}%
      \@tempa
      \if@nobreak
        \ifvmode
          \nobreak
        \fi
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \relax}

%%
%%  The \startingpagenumber command will change the default starting
%%  page number for the first (title) page of the current volume and
%%  for the first page after the preface section.
%%
\def\@startpageA{1}
\def\@startpageB{1}

\def\startingpagenumber#1#2{%
  \gdef\@startpageA{#1}%
  \gdef\@startpageB{#2}}

%%
%% The following flag is used to suppress the major field name on the
%% title page when the default school is changed (only the GRADUATE
%% SCHOOL currently uses a major field).  Setting \majorfield after
%% \schoolname will reset the flag and allow the printing of another
%% school with a major field in addition.
%%
\newif\ifshowmajorfield
\showmajorfieldtrue

\def\universityname#1{%
  \gdef\@university{\uppercase{#1}}}
\def\@university{UNIVERSITY OF SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA}

\def\schoolname#1{%
  \gdef\@schoolname{#1}%
  \showmajorfieldfalse}
\def\@schoolname{GRADUATE SCHOOL}

\def\degree#1{%
  \ifthesis
    \gdef\@mastersdegree{#1}%
  \else
    \gdef\@doctorsdegree{#1}}
\def\@mastersdegree{MASTER OF SCIENCE}
\def\@doctorsdegree{DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY}

\def\majorfield#1{%
  \gdef\@majorfield{#1}%
  \showmajorfieldtrue}
\def\@majorfield{Electrical Engineering}

\def\committee#1{\gdef\@committee{#1}}
\def\@committee{}

\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}
\def\@submitdate{%
  \ifcase \the\month
    \or January%
    \or February%
    \or March%
    \or April%
    \or May%
    \or June%
    \or July%
    \or August%
    \or September%
    \or October%
    \or November%
    \or December%
  \fi
  \space
  \number \the\year}

\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}}
%% December dissertations should have the next year as the copyright year
\ifnum \month=12
  \@tempcnta=\year
  \advance\@tempcnta by 1
  \edef\@copyrightyear{\number \the\@tempcnta}
\else
  \def\@copyrightyear{\number \the\year}
\fi

%%
%% Create the PREFACE environment.  The titlepage is generated when
%% the environment is first entered and the numbering is roman within
%% the preface.  The \endpreface switches to arabic numbering.
%%
\newenvironment{preface}{%
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{roman}%
  \pagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{singlespace}%
    \ifproposal
      \makeproptitle
      \setcounter{page}{1}%
      \addtocounter{page}{\@startpageA}% Advance page counter for title page.
    \else
      \maketitle
      \setcounter{page}{1}%
      \addtocounter{page}{\@startpageA}% Advance page counter for (signature
    \fi                                %   and) title.  At USC, the signature
 \newpage                              %   page is not counted!
    \ifx\@volume\@empty\else % Add Volume ID to contents if present.
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\@volume}{}}%
    \fi
  \end{singlespace}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}{%
  \newpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \pagestyle{plain}%
  \setcounter{page}{\@startpageB}}

%%
%% Define the PROPOSAL title page
%%
\def\makeproptitle{%
  \begin{titlepage}%
    \null
    \vskip 60.0 true pt%          To adjust centering.
    \begin{center}
      {\Large \@title \par}%      Set title in \Large size.
      \ifx\@volume\@empty\else
        \vskip 3em%               Vertical space before volume.
        \@volume
      \fi
      \vskip 3em%                 Vertical space after title.
      \ifthesis
        {Masters Thesis Proposal}%
      \else
        {Ph.D. Dissertation Proposal}%
      \fi\\*%
      {submitted by}%
      \vskip 3em                % Vertical space before author.
      {\lineskip .75em
       \@author
       \par}%
      \vskip 1.5cm              % Vertical space before date.
      {\small
        \@submitdate
        \par}%
      \vskip 1.5in
      {{\bf Qualifying Exam Committee}\\*[1.0 true cm]%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{ll}\@committee
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \end{center}%
    \par
    \vfil
    \end{titlepage}}

%%
%% Make the Dissertation titlepage
%%
\def\maketitle{%
  \large  % title page should be 11pt or 12pt.  this should do.
  \begin{titlepage}%
    \setcounter{page}{0}%
    \null
    \vfill%\vfill
    \begin{center}%
      {\@title \par}%         Set title the same size as "FACULTY OF ..."
      \ifx\@volume\@empty\else
        \vskip 0.16 true in
        \@volume
      \fi
      \vskip 0.5 true in
      by%
      \vskip 0.5 true in
      {\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author\\*[.66 true in]%
       \rule{5.0 true in}{0.025 true in}
       \end{tabular}%
       \par}
      \vskip 1.0 true in
      \ifthesis
        A Thesis Presented to the%
      \else
        A Dissertation Presented to the%
      \fi\\%*[0.1 true in]%
      FACULTY OF THE \@schoolname\\%*[0.1 true in]%
      \@university\\%*[0.1 true in]%
      In Partial Fulfillment of the\\%*[0.1 true in]%
      Requirements for the Degree\\%*[0.1 true in]%
      \ifthesis
        \@mastersdegree
      \else
        \@doctorsdegree
      \fi\\%*[0.1 true in]%
      \ifshowmajorfield
        (\@majorfield)%
      \fi\\%*[1.0 true cm]%
      %\vfill
      \vskip 0.75 true in
      \@submitdate%   should be just month and year
    \end{center}%
    \par
    \vfill
    \ifcopyright
          \noindent Copyright~ \@copyrightyear \hfill \@author
    \fi
  \end{titlepage}}

%%
%% Start a Preface Page
%%
\newdimen\prefacetopspace
\prefacetopspace=1.0 true in

\def\prefacesection{%
  \@ifnextchar [%
    {\@prefacesectionB}%
    {\@prefacesectionA}}

\def\@prefacesectionA#1{%
  \@prefacesectionB[#1]{#1}}

\def\@prefacesectionB[#1]#2{%
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{plain}%
  \null
  \vskip\prefacetopspace
  %\begin{center}%
    \section*{#2}%
  %\end{center}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

%%
%% Make the Table of Contents and Figures/Tables pages
%%
\def\tableofcontents{%
  \begin{singlespace}
  \@ifnextchar [%
    {\@starspeciallist{toc}}%
    {\@starspeciallist{toc}[Table of Contents]}
  \end{singlespace}}

\def\listoftables{%
  \@ifstar
    {\@ifnextchar [%
       {\@starspeciallist{lot}}%
       {\@starspeciallist{lot}[List Of Tables]}}%
    {\@ifnextchar [%
       {\@speciallist{lot}}%
       {\@speciallist{lot}[List Of Tables]}}}

\def\listoffigures{%
  \@ifstar
    {\@ifnextchar [%
       {\@starspeciallist{lof}}%
       {\@starspeciallist{lof}[List Of Figures]}}%
    {\@ifnextchar [%
       {\@speciallist{lof}}%
       {\@speciallist{lof}[List Of Figures]}}}


% redefine commands used to generate entries in lof and lot, in order to make
% them singlespace within each entry (leaving doublespace between entries)
\renewcommand*\l@figure[2]{
  \begin{singlespace}
  \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}
  \end{singlespace}
}
\let\l@table\l@figure

\def\@starspeciallist#1[#2]{%
  \newpage
  \@restonecolfalse
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue
    \onecolumn
  \fi
  \chapter*{#2}%
  \@starttoc{#1}%
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}

\def\@speciallist#1[#2]{%
  \newpage
  \@restonecolfalse
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue
    \onecolumn
  \fi
  \chapter*{#2}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
  \@starttoc{#1}%
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}

%%
%% Redefine the report.sty chapter definitions to suppress hyphenation
%% in the titles.
%%
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50pt}%
  {\parindent 0pt
   \raggedright
   \hyphenpenalty 10000%
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth > \m@ne
     \Large\bf \@chapapp{} \thechapter\par
     \vskip 20pt
   \fi
   \Large\bf #1\par
   \nobreak
   \vskip 40pt}
  \hyphenpenalty 50}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50pt}%
  {\parindent 0pt
   \raggedright
   \hyphenpenalty 10000%
   \Large\bf #1\par
   \nobreak
   \vskip 40pt}
  \hyphenpenalty 50}

%%
%% Redefine the report.sty section definitions.  The \@startsection
%% command takes the arguments:
%%
%%       {Name}{Level}{Indent}{BeforeSkip}{AfterSkip}{Style}
%%
%% ABS(BeforeSkip) == amount to skip; if (BeforeSkip < 0), suppress
%% the par indent of the text following the heading.
%%
%% ABS(AfterSkip) == amount to skip; if (AfterSkip < 0), make the
%% following text "run-in" after the heading.
%%
%% Also new section takes a `*' which suppress the section counting,
%% and if the `*' is not present an optional [Altheading]{heading}
%% pair.
%%

% also, redefine the \chapter command in order to remove the inter-chapter
% spacing that is normally added to the LOF and LOT
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                      \thispagestyle{plain}%
                      \global\@topnum\z@
                      \@afterindentfalse
                      \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {Chapter \protect\numberline{\thechapter:}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter: #1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    %\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    %\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

\def\section{\@startsection{section}%                    Name
            {1}%                                         Level
            {\z@}%                                       Indent
            {-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}%              BeforeSkip
            {2.3ex plus .2ex}%                           AfterSkip
            {\Large\bf\hyphenpenalty 10000}}%            Style

\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}%              Name
               {2}%                                      Level
               {\z@}%                                    Indent
               {-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}%           BeforeSkip
               {1.5ex plus .2ex}%                        AfterSkip
               {\large\bf\hyphenpenalty 10000}}%         Style

\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}%        Name
                  {3}%                                   Level
                  {\z@}%                                 Indent
                  {-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}%        BeforeSkip
                  {1.5ex plus .2ex}%                     AfterSkip
                  {\normalsize\bf\hyphenpenalty 10000}}% Style

\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}%                Name
              {4}%                                       Level
              {\z@}%                                     Indent
              {3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}%              BeforeSkip
              {-1em}%                                    AfterSkip
              {\normalsize\bf\hyphenpenalty 10000}}%     Style

\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}%          Name
                 {4}%                                    Level
                 {\parindent}%                           Indent
                 {3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}%           BeforeSkip
                 {-1em}%                                 AfterSkip
                 {\normalsize\bf\hyphenpenalty 10000}}%  Style

%%
%% The value of the counter secnumdepth gives the depth of the
%% highest-level sectioning command that is to produce section
%% numbers.
%%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%%
%% Redefine the report.sty `Bibliography' as a `Reference List' chapter.
%%
\def\bibliographystyle#1{%   But first, turn off standard bib commands.
  \@latexerr{\string\bibliographystyle\space is undefined.
         Use \string\references{#1}{bibfile list}}\@eha}
\def\bibliography#1{%
  \@latexerr{\string\bibliography\space is undefined.
         Use \string\references{bibstyle}{#1}}\@eha}

\def\references{%
  \@ifstar
    {\@referencesA}%
    {\@referencesB}}

\def\@referencesA{%
  \@ifnextchar [%
    {\@referencesAA}%
    {\@referencesAA[Reference List]}}%

\def\@referencesAA[#1]#2#3{
  \gdef\@referencesname{#1}
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibstyle{#2}}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#3}}%
  \fi
  \@input{\jobname.bbl}}

\def\@referencesB{
  \@ifnextchar [
    {\@referencesBB}
    {\@referencesBB[Reference List]}}

\def\@referencesBB[#1]#2#3{
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \gdef\@referencesname{#1}
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibstyle{#2}}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#3}}%
  \fi
  \@input{\jobname.bbl}}

\def\@referencesname{Reference List}

\def\thebibliography#1{
  \chapter*{\@referencesname\@mkboth{\@referencesname}{\@referencesname}}
  \list{[\arabic{enumi}]}{
    \settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}
    \leftmargin\labelwidth   \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \ifopenbib
      \listparindent -1.5em
      \advance\leftmargin-\listparindent
      \itemindent\listparindent
      \parsep 0pt%
    \fi
    \usecounter{enumi}}%
  \ifopenbib
    \def\newblock{\par}
    \let\\=\@centercr
    \@rightskip\@flushglue   \rightskip\@rightskip
    \leftskip\z@
  \else
    \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus -.07em}%
  \fi
  \sloppy
  \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

%%
%% APPENDIX
%%
%% The \appendix command must do the following:
%%    -- reset the chapter counter to zero
%%    -- set \@chapapp to Appendix (for messages)
%%    -- redefine the chapter counter to produce appendix numbers
%%    -- reset the section counter to zero
%%    -- redefine the \chapter command if appendix titles and headings
%%       are to look different from chapter titles and headings.
%%
%% For USC, the Appendix appears VERY oddly in the table of contents.
%%
\def\appendix{
  \par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \def\@chapapp{Appendix}
  \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
  \def\@chapter[##1]##2{
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
    \addtocontents{toc}{
      \protect\contentsline{chapter}{Appendix \thechapter}{\relax}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{##1}
    \chaptermark{##1}
    %\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}% Adds between-chapter space
    %\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}% to lists of figs & tables.
    \if@twocolumn
      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{##2}]
    \else \@makechapterhead{##2}
      \@afterheading                             % Routine called after chap
    \fi}}                                        %   and section heading.

%%
%%  Define the `saying' environment
%%  Used to set a cutesy little quotation at the start of the chapter
%%
\def\saying{%
  \trivlist
  \raggedleft
  \item[]\em}

\def\endsaying{%
  \endtrivlist
  \vspace{20pt}}

%%
%% Define the starting pagestyle
%%
\pagestyle{plain}
```

When I compile the following example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
% [options] can be any of these default/alternative flag:
%   dissertation/thesis, final/proposal, copyright/nocopyright,
%   fussy/sloppy, flushbottom/raggedbottom, clref/opref.
\usepackage[dissertation]{USCthesis}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,titlesec,xcolor,enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{section}{1.4 Notion of a Solution}
This is just a test to see if it's doing what I think it's doing.
\begin{align}
    2 + 2 =& 4\\
    1 +87 =& 88
\end{align}
I'm now going to add a little more text. Maybe another new equation line. Something simple like the above
\begin{equation}
    99 + 101 = 200.
\end{equation}
\end{section}
\end{document}
```

It outputs [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtZst.png).
But when I compile this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
% [options] can be any of these default/alternative flag:
%   dissertation/thesis, final/proposal, copyright/nocopyright,
%   fussy/sloppy, flushbottom/raggedbottom, clref/opref.
\usepackage[dissertation]{USCthesis}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,titlesec,xcolor,enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{section}{1.4 Notion of a Solution}
This is just a test to see if it's doing what I think it's doing.
\begin{align}
    2 + 2 =& 4\\
    1 +87 =& 88
\end{align}
I'm now going to add a little more text. Maybe another new equation line. Something simple like the above
\begin{equation}
    99 + 101 = 200.
\end{equation}
There's still about half of a page left. But now I want a "long" stream of aligned equations that will likely bleed onto the next page, but then it's going to add a bunch of white space up top
\begin{align}
    1 =&1\\
    2=&2\\
    3=&3\\
    4=&4\\
    5=&5
\end{align}
\end{section}
\end{document}
```

It outputs [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBID8.png).
I'd appreciate any help on getting rid of that huge vertical space. At the very least, I'd like to keep the text above the long stream of equations on the first page instead of keeping it all together.

Comment: For now, I've realigned my 5 equations at the bottom, but I'd still like to know what's going on since I'm sure I'll encounter this again later in my thesis.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why do you number your sections manually (see `\begin{section}{1.4 Notion of a Solution}`)  and where is the `section` environment defined?

Comment: Regarding the large white space: Did you already ty with the `raggedbottom` option of `USCthesis` (as your example documents tell you in line 2-4: "% [options] can be any of these default/alternative flag:
%   dissertation/thesis, final/proposal, copyright/nocopyright,
%   fussy/sloppy, flushbottom/raggedbottom, clref/opref.")

Comment: To enable page breaks inside of `align` environments (as it would be needed in your last example) you might want to add `\allowdisplaybreaks` to our preamble.

Comment: @leandriis I do not. But after browsing this community for a while, I know people like "working examples." I of course do not number them manually, but as the images come from the fourth section of my actual thesis, I wanted to mimic it as much as possible when posting here.

Comment: @leandriis which would you recommend? I've never dealt with either "bottom" commands. And thanks for the other display suggestion.